# Ctrl-Backspace not working in ReSharper's "Navigate to Everything/Type"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is a known bug, but when I open "Navigate to Everything/Type" via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, type something and then try to delete it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>, it will just insert a *box* character.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looks to already be a known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-85494).  Seems to have been introduced around version 6 according to a commenter there, and <s>still exists to the latest version, 8.2.1.</s> has been fixed in 9.1.

Answer (score 1):

As of JetBrains' guy's comment [in here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-85494)

> Guys, fix will be available in the upcoming R# 9.1 EAP4 build

It's really already fixed! Tried Resharper 9.2 and... Hallelujah!